# Android Stuido: How to change Kotlin version that is used for building with Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

Android Studio is giving a warning saying: "Kotlin version that is used for building with Gradle (1.3.10) differs from the one bundled into the IDE plugin (1.3.41)".

How can i change the Kotlin version used by Gradle?

I have installed the latest Android Studio version(3.4.2) with the latest Kotlin plugin(1.3.41-release-Studio3.4-1)

I have also tried to change the kotlin version in the build.gradle file, but its saved in a variable "kotlin_version$"

```
dependencies {
    // ....
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I have also tried to change the kotlin version in the build.gradle file, but its saved in a variable "kotlin_version$"

That variable is defined earlier in the file. Here is a typical top-level `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.41'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The second line of that file is:

```
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.41'
```

That is where `kotlin_version` is defined, that is then used in `"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"`.

So, change `ext.kotlin_version` to be the value that you want.

Comment: Thank you, it was very simple after all. :)

Comment: I'm using studio v2020.3.1 patch 3 ... kotlin_version is in `build.gradle (Project)` not `build.gradle (Module)`

Comment: @duanev: Correct! What I referred to as a "top-level `build.gradle` file" is what you referred to `build.gradle (Project)`.